# Replace spaces with %20in the URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following line on my sendEmail function in google app script

```
tempo.getRange(lastRow, 12).setFormula('="www.sample"&R[0]C[-1]&"collection.com"');
```

some of the result has space in between like this

www.samplespot lightcollection.com

which is resulting for a hyperlink to break.

Can someone in help replacing the space with %20 using google appscript?

The final result should look like this

www.samplespot%20lightcollection.com

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
tempo.getRange(lastRow, 12).setFormula('="www.sample"&R[0]C[-1]&"collection.com"');
```

#### To:

```
tempo.getRange(lastRow, 12).setFormula('=ENCODEURL("www.sample"&R[0]C[-1]&"collection.com")');
```

- In this case, when the value of last row of column "K" is `spot light`, the column "L" shows `www.samplespot%20lightcollection.com`.

#### Reference:

- [ENCODEURL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9199778?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop:

```py
a = list('www.samplespot lightcollection.com')
for b, c in enumerate(a):
    if c == ' ':
        a[b] = '%20'
a = ''.join(a)
print(a)
```

Can be shortened into a function:

```py
replace = lambda a: ''.join(['%20' if c == ' ' else c for b, c in enumerate(list(a))])
print(replace('www.samplespot lightcollection.com'))
```

Comment: What should I change 'www.samplespot lightcollection.com' with? As you can see I am using R[0]C[-1] as the source is dynamic. 

Sorry if my question is messy, I am totally new to scripting.

Comment: This answer may work, but it does not seem to use Google Apps Script as specified by OP's tags.